# JavaFx Text wrap in TableCell

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, word-wrap

I have a problem with text wrapping in the TableCells, one of them if I change the cell's data the text wrap is not working automatic, just if I do some hack. I am curious if someone had the same problem that I have an maybe have found a better solution.

Here is a simple example you can verify:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Model> table;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Model, String> colA;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Model, String> colB;
    @FXML
    private Button changeString;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        colA.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().stringA);
        colB.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().stringB);

        setCellFactory();

        ObservableList<Model> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        items.add(new Model("This is a long string that needs to be wrapped", "Short"));
        items.add(new Model("This is a long string that needs to be wrapped", "Short"));

        changeString.setOnAction(event -> {
            table.getItems().get(0).getStringA().setValue("Short");
            table.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(false);
            table.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(true);
        });

        table.setItems(items);
    }

    private void setCellFactory() {
        colA.setCellFactory(f -> {
            TableCell<Model, String> cell = new TableCell<Model, String>() {
                Text text = new Text();

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                        return;
                    }
                    text.setWrappingWidth(getTableColumn().getWidth() - 10);
                    text.setText(item);
                    setGraphic(text);
                }
            };
            return cell;
        });
    }

    @Getter
    private static class Model {

        private final StringProperty stringA;
        private final StringProperty stringB;

        private Model(String stringA, String stringB) {
            this.stringA = new SimpleStringProperty(stringA);
            this.stringB = new SimpleStringProperty(stringB);
        }
    }
}
```

*(This is only the relevant part, i will include the `Main` and the `fxml` if needed)*

As you can see I have to set a value in the model which is displayed in a table cell but after is set the height of the cell is not updated. I order to update it i have to include that column hide/show hack to refresh the height.

Do you have any better suggestion/solution to this problem?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44128787/3625077, bind wrappingWidthProperty with the column widthProperty

Comment: That doesn't help...I set the wrappingWidth every time before the text is set as Graphic.

Comment: Do you need a `Text`? Shapes are not managed by default, so I'm not surprised the cell height does not automatically change. Cell heights are problematic in general, but does it work if you just call methods directly on the cell (`setWrapText(...)`, `setText(...)`, etc). Or, at worst, use a `Label` for the graphic.

Comment: @James_D I tried both. setWrapText does nothing, it cuts the ... at the end of the text but it doesn't display the whole text, so it doesn't update the height of the cell at all. Using a label is the same, it doesn't have `wrappingWIdth` property to bind it. At every wraptext related question I found only this `Text` based one. This works in a way but that refresh part is not so nice.

Comment: hmm ... looks like the computation of prefHeight in the row happens _before_ the cell content is updated. Tried to somehow force that after, no success, sry. An aside (doesn't help to solve your problem, just for code sanity :) - as the wrappingWidth is not related to the cell content but to the column width, it should be bound to that property (with guarding against no-column, of course) outside of updateItem.

Comment: @kleopatra Yes you are right it should not be there, but I noticed a weird behaviour with binding and this solved for me. Since the cells are reused, it happened that the binding didn't trigger if I removed a row and then re-added it, and the cell's text wasn't wrapped.

Comment: thanks for the info, will add to my tests :)

Comment: After a bit more testing I noticed that I need both, so I used the binding and the set value but only when I set the `Text` as graphics. (like unbind/set/bind)

Answer (score -1):

This has to do with your updateItem in your setCellFactory being in the main thread.  Change your cell factory to run in the FX thread like so

```
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    Platform.runLater(() -> {
                        if (empty) {
                            setGraphic(null);
                        } else {
                            text.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(getTableColumn().widthProperty().subtract(10));
                            text.setText(item);
                            setGraphic(text);
                        }
                    });

                }
            };
        });
    }
```

And you can remove the column visible hack in your changeString.setOnAction event

Alternatively, since it's thought that `runLater` is a hack use the tableview refresh... With only your original code snippet, instead of

```
       changeString.setOnAction(event -> {
            table.getItems().get(0).getStringA().setValue("Short");
            table.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(false);
            table.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(true);
        });
```

replace with this

```
       changeString.setOnAction(event -> {
            table.getItems().get(0).getStringA().setValue("Short");
            table.refresh();
        });
```

Comment: .. looks like it might work (I assume you tested it?), if so you should do the binding outside of updateItem (please read my comment to the question :) As to hack level: using runlater is about at the same level as hide/show .. but then anything is okay when it comes working around to borderline bugs :)

Comment: I tested it, the binding in the fx thread is working, but I do agree the width binding should be in the initialize method.  Without seeing OP's full code, this is highly dependent on how he is setting the (pref)width of the table column.

Comment: curious: why would it dependend on the pref settings? either the column is resizable or not, binding to the width will work in the former and not in the latter case. Repeating: the wrappingWidth is _not_ dependent on the content but on the column width, so it doesn't belong into updateItem.

Comment: When testing, I had no code for column widths in fxml, or in the controller, and the column would be drawn at 1 character width.  If I set a pref width, say 40, column would wrap at 40, and when the button pressed event was fired, would automatically resize the hright as OP is wanting

Comment: that's unusual behavior (without any explicit setting the skin sizing of columns defaults to 80) .. but thanks for the info :)

Comment: The updateItem event is getting fired multiple times, in the initialize method, column width IS 80, but after the 3rd time the update item event is fired, the column width is somehow changed to 20, tested with logging of width added to initialize and to updateItem after the call to super.updateItem(item, empty);

Comment: @b3tuning as kleopatra said this would be on the *hack* side as well as show/hide. As a solution I would expect a clean way without `Platform.runLater()`

Comment: I'm really curious why updateItem is being called exactly 17 times.  If you add a log to updateItem() you can verify for yourself.

Comment: So than am I to assume then that this is an exercise in the limitations of controls with row heights that are not dynamic? TableView(any Control that has a List backing) has more emphasis on maintaining the weakListeners for columns, and content width, but none for evaluating the needed height. Is this by design for already lackluster performance, or from the underlying implementation of Labeled as TableCell?

Comment: If you reverse the strings so short is in the column during init, and button press updates to the long string, the cell/row acts as though fixed cell size and the string is clipped

Comment: Yeah refresh is worst :D I used table.refresh like 2 years ago then I noticed that, to refresh a cell is better to use column hide/show, but i cannot find a better way :(